# Ubuntu 14.04 Server - Apache2 Webdav Error

Tags: 14.04, apache2, webdav

I have set up Ubuntu 14.04 Server on a VPS and installed LAMP.  I have also enabled the webDav modules as well as set up an alias to the directory and digest authentication.

```
Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav

<Directory /var/www/webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I have connected to the Ubuntu server webdav filesystem fine with the user I created and I can create files via webdav.  My problem is, when I attempt to view files in any subfolder, I get an error

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G6xa.png)

I don't see anything in the apache logs related to the files or folders I'm trying to view.  Any direction here would be appreciated.